# Rotate picture with caption

Tags: floats, captions, rotating

How can I rotate both a picture and its title in TeX?

Parameter in `\includegraphics` allows to rotate only a picture.

Answer (score 31):

This can be done using the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package. The solution is similar to the one of Werner but saves you some manual work with saveboxes. Note that `adjustbox` v1.0 also includes a `figure` key which allows to add the figure environment automatically as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{%
      Here is a caption of the figure which is so long that 
      it has to be wrapped over multiple lines, but should 
      not exceed the width (height after the rotation) of the image.
      }\end{minipage}},rotate=90,center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.6]{example-image}%
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Is it possible to rotate by 90 or 270 deg depending on whether the page is even or odd?

Comment: Worth noticing is that it is often recommended to always rotate all pictures in the same direction so that the reader only have to read the book in two direction and not in three, i.e. always have to turn the whole book in the same direction. I am pretty sure Bringhurst recommends this for example.

Comment: @jonalv: Yes, I also know it to rotate them so that the lower side is on the right.

Comment: Can you suggest where to out \label? I tried all possibilities but hopeless.

Comment: @chandresh: Try it inside `\caption` at the very end just before the `}`.

Comment: For some reasons this would not completely work for me with the packages I had loaded. The caption was not rotated. The solution posted by @Chogg worked for me though.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 30):

The `rotating` package and `sidewaysfigure` environment can rotate the figure and caption as you ask. The figure will be placed on a separate page.

The method is described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations).

A minimum working example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{file}%
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{subfigure}` package, caption title and `\documentclass{article}` are missing in code. one might use [`\usepackage{mwe}`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) to use `example-image-a` instead of `file`

Comment: By the way, subfigure is deprecated, see e.g. description at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure. I don't really see why you use a subfigure at all, it's not necessary.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right. I've updated it. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I think this is the simplest solution. You can also rotate a table like this using `sidewaystable`.

Comment: Is it possible that it won't be placed on a new page? I want it directly below a `\chapter{}`.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an elementary way of accomplishing a rotation. It requires boxing the figure contents (via a `minipage`) before rotating it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newsavebox{\myimage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \savebox{\myimage}{\rule{100pt}{150pt}}% Image to be included
  \rotatebox{90}{% Rotate 90 CCW
    \begin{minipage}{\wd\myimage}
      \usebox{\myimage}
      \caption{Here is a caption of the figure.}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image is saved in a box `\myimage` in order to obtain its width (`\wd\myimage`). This is then used to set the width of the `minipage`. I used a dummy 100pt x 150pt black rectangle.

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to generate dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Answer (score 10):

run `texdoc hvfloat` for the documentation of the different keywords

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{hvfloat,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\hvFloat[
 floatPos=!htb,
 capWidth=h,
 capPos=r,
 capAngle=90,
 objectAngle=90,
 capVPos=c,
 objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{tiger}}%
{Caption vertically centered right beside the float with a caption
width of figure width and 
\texttt{floatcapsep=5pt} (the default)}{fig:label}

\listoffigures    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with this method, the figure doesn't apprear in the list of figures

Comment: I see. Will upload an updated version to CTAN.

Comment: it's on CTAN: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hvfloat/latex

Answer (score 4):

Simply put `angle=X` in the `\includegraphics` command. For example

```
 \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, angle=90]{fig.eps}
    \caption{The caption}
    \label{cap}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer because it rotates only the figure and NOT the caption. The question specifically asked for a solution to rotating BOTH figure and caption and notes that your solution rotates only the image. "Parameter in \includegraphics allows to rotate only a picture."