# How to fix issues after rotating a table with sidewaystable directly below the Chapter title?

Tags: rotating

I am trying to get a big table in the Appendix, directly below the chapter title.

Sidewaystable from the rotating package works, since it nicely rotates the entire table, including caption and footnotes.

After searching a while, I found that the floatrow package adds the [H] option to the sidewaystable-environment, such that it can be forced to be placed at a specific location.

However, when adding that option to the table below the chapter title, not the table is sitting below the title but the title slides down and sits above the table. In result, an additional blank page is left before the title. 
Moreover, the title is below a header, which I was unable to remove through \thispagestyle{empty}. I have added a minimal working example below.

Is there a way to move the table up instead of the title down, in order to fix (i) the empty page and (ii) the header occurrence?

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix}
\begin{sidewaystable}[H]
\caption{Experimental settings.}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule 
Test & Yes & No & Yes \tabularnewline
\midrule
1  & 2 & 3 & 4\footnote{This is absolutely necessary information with reference to 4.}                   
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table_exp_settings}
\end{sidewaystable}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption

Comment: Ok, thx for your suggestions. However, I figured that my main problem is another one. Apparently, a chapter title is drawn to the next page (an even page), when it is followed by a big float filling the whole page, which comes with the [H] option for positioning. This seems to be true for figures as well as the abovementioned sidewaystable.

Comment: I opened a new Question on that problem at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200131/chapter-title-cannot-be-drawn-next-to-big-figure-with-h-option

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix}

\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{.5\textheight}{%
\centering
\captionof{table}{Experimental settings.}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule 
Test & Yes & No & Yes \tabularnewline
\midrule
1  & 2 & 3 & 4\footnote{This is absolutely necessary information with reference to 4.}                   
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table_exp_settings}
}}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```