# I can't rotate the caption when rotating image to face the left

Tags: floats, rotating

How can I include the caption to fit below the figure when turned 90 degrees to face the left? this code should work but I'm not sure why it isn't, possibly due to the captionsetup?

here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}



\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\begin{document}
\sloppy

\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{turn}{-90}
    \begin{minipage}{8in}
    \centering  
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{reggrid_Vs_Alongtrackgrid.eps}
    \caption{A comparison between SSH [mm] averaged between 31$^{st}$ December, 1992 to 9$^{th}$ January, 1993 on a regular grid (top) and SSH [mm] along track during the same period (bottom).}
    \label{fig:reggrid_Vs_Alongtrackgrid}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
\end{figure}
```

Is anyone else having trouble logging into the website? I try to log in but it doesn't work so I created a new account and this still brings up a page error. it's annoying because I have to create new questions rather than adding to the original :-(

thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

This has been already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption?rq=1). But anyway, here it is for your case.

You should not call the package `caption` and `graphicx` twice. Then you need package `adjustbox` from [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox).

The minimal code will be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

Some text here.

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{4in}}{%  
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{noimage}
    \caption{A comparison between SSH [mm] averaged between 31$^\mathrm{st}$ December, 1992 to 9$^\mathrm{th}$ January, 1993 on a regular grid (top) and SSH [mm] along track during the same period (bottom).}%
    \label{fig:reggrid_Vs_Alongtrackgrid}
    \end{minipage}},rotate=90,center}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

Follow by some text here.

\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by the `\captionsetup`, if you by trial and error remove all the packages not influencing the problem, you're left with

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{turn}{-90}
        \begin{minipage}{8in}
        \centering  
            \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Text}
        \label{fig:reggrid_Vs_Alongtrackgrid}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{turn}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

This code shows the problem, but if you remove

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
```

it works fine. Exactly why it happens I do not know, perhaps `floatrow` redefines `\caption` or something.

If you're using `floatrow` only to place a caption beside a figure, then you can remove it and use a pair of `minipage`s, as in the code below. Note that I changed the width of the `minipage` in the `turn` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{turn}{-90}
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \centering  
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Text}
    \label{fig:reggrid_Vs_Alongtrackgrid}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\caption{Annual and semi-annual harmonics calculated from along-track weighted altimetry data.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And as Václav Pavlík says, there is no need to load packages more than once. You have two of `tocloft` as well.

[image]