# Tikz - Rotated Gaussian

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, plot

I would like to plot a rotated curve (gaussian) but I've got no idea how. I searched in the internet and found that I have to define the gaussian curve because it's not included. But how can I plot such a function rotated by 270°?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could plot your Gaussian curve with `1/sqrt(2pi)e^{-x^2/2}` in `PGFPlots`.  Then you could use the `standalone` package to include the figure and use the options to rotate the image.

```
\begin{figure}
\includestandalone[mode = image]{myplot}
\end{figure}
```

Here is a post on 4 different ways to rotate a figure: [Rotate picture with caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption)

Or you could simply rotate the PGFPlots with option rotate around = 270 and then insert standalone figure.

How to make the plot rotated:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
anchor = origin,
rotate around={270:(current axis.origin)},
hide axis
]
\addplot[smooth, domain=-5:5] {1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-\x^2/2)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer! I've got another question: In my plot there are three curves with axis (plotted without pgf) in a row. I need to add this plot to the row of my pictures (as fourth plot) and connect the thirt picture with the fourth by a dashed line. Is it possible to connect a pgf picture with a normal one? The Axis have to be on the same height.

Comment: @Deuterium42 you should start a new question and post the code and image of what you have currently so it will be easy to understand for the answerers.

Comment: Ok, I will post it later/tomorrow because I'm on the way home now and posting via smartphone (where I haven't the code)

Comment: Hey, I've included your code to my one and it works! But one last question left: Is it possible to shift the curve to a given coordinate e.g. (3.0,30)?

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem by shifting the function due to the x arguement. Thanks for your patience!