# In Miktex (Latex), how do I rotate figure and fill the entire page with it?

Tags: rotating, floats, miktex

I have a horizontal (say A3 page) .eps figure which I want to import into Miktex generated text, rotating it so that it will fill the entire A4 page rather than occupy only it's say 30% when imported vertically.

How do I do that?

I came across the rotation option but it didn't work nicely and moreover I didn't manage to find a working example that rotates the figure and the caption.

Three possible ways to rotate that I tried, following a request for a working example:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,angle=90]{Image.eps}
}
\caption{Example}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

and

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Image.eps}%
}
\caption{Example}
\label{fig:example}

\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

and

```
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\vspace*{-10mm}\caption{
      Example
      }\end{minipage}},rotate=90,right}
      \includegraphics[scale=.4]{Image.eps}%
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
```

Neither rotates the caption. In the first case the capture is right-biased as well as in the last one (it also moves beyond the margins of the page)... In the second case, the caption is at least centralized :-(

There are many excellent solutions on `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption` but unfortunately nothing seems to work - even the

```
\lipsum[2]
\hvFloat[
 floatPos=!htb,
 capWidth=h,
 capPos=r,
 capAngle=90,
 objectAngle=90,
 capVPos=c,
 objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Image.eps}}%
{Example}{fig:label}
```

rotates the image well (tiger example in the above link), but the caption is right-placed and not rotated...

I added an example of fig and what it gives with rotations above:
[image: Original image]
[image: Rotated image. As you may see, the caption is on the right but is not rotated]
(*) The example is from the Matlab standard library...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is doable. Do you have other content around this full-page image that you want to import? Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use as a point of departure?

Comment: @Werner - I added two working examples. I also tried \tikz but since I work with eps it didn't work at all and wrapping the eps as dvi didn't go too well too, hence I omitted these from working examples. Thanks!

Comment: What is critical and now clear from the newly-posted examples, is that you not only want the figure to be rotated, but the caption as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve it, use the `landscape` package. I put two includegraphics because it depends on the size of your image.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Image.eps}
    \includegraphics[height=0.95\textheight]{Image.eps}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but this solution also does not rotate the caption - it merely places it to the right of the text but still vertically (e.g., 90degrees to the desired angle) I use  \usepackage{lscape} and \usepackage{graphicx} over WinEdt5, V5.5 over MikTex 2.9.. When I change the size of the fig, the caption does seem to move (like if moving to the next line but it is still vertical) \vspace and \hspace do not seem to change anything too.. I want to reader be able to look at the fig and read the capture without rotating the page. Maybe I should change the def of the page? How?..

Comment: I am confused because your first solution `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,angle=90]{Image.eps}` and my solution with `landscape` can provide you the most common ways to have the caption for your file. Maybe, you can provide us an a full picture or a drawing with your needs to help us understand what you really want to do?

Comment: the example is provided in the question description. thanks

Comment: If the second image is the result of `includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,angle=90]{Image.eps}` the trouble comes from you Tex Environment. When you open the pdf or dvi file, can you see your caption? To my mind, i think we provide you the solution, but it does not work because of your "Miktex generated text".

Comment: @Lopzo - you are a genius! while the dvi looks incorrect, the pdf looks perfectly fine with most options from above including your solution! I never thought to look at the PDF since the DVI was wrong (the example I gave is a screenshot of DVI). THANK YOU! BTW - what environment are you using if not Miktex? Plain Latex?

Comment: I am working on linux with TeX Live, vim (with plugins) and evince to display pdf files. Do not forget to validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every solution from the above works fine when generating the PDF file with these solutions. The DVI file does not look right though, but converting from DVI to PDF places the caption where it should be. I am not sure if this is due to the Miktex environment as suggested by @Lopezo or because of using WinEdt, but these solutions do work when generating a PDF output by converting from DVI to PDF with WinEdt over MikTex.