# Vertical footnotes in rotated and boxed figures

Tags: floats, captions, rotating

My intention is to have a figure rotated and boxed with a tiny border just behind the limits of the figure.

I found a solution to rotate figures in
[Rotate picture with caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption)

But when I add these line in the preamble

```
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

then the caption rotation is not working. Note that between the border and the figure there are white spaces (which I prefer to avoid them).

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{DissertateB5}
\captionsetup{labelfont=\rmdefault, textfont=\rmdefault }
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{Visualización de los datos en Kibana}\label{fig:kibana} \end{minipage}},rotate=90,center}
      \includegraphics[scale=.4]{kibana.png}
  \end{adjustbox}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter done...

Comment: That's not a complete MWE. You haven't loaded any packages, e.g. `float`, `adjustbox`, `caption` etc., thus your code won't compile anyway.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a standard class? If so, substitute that in the MWE. If not, we'll need a link as it means the issue is specific to the custom class you're using.

Comment: `thesis` is not a standard class - this does not help us any more then `DissertateB5`. Can you reproduce your problem with something like `book`, `article`, `report` etc.?

Comment: Did you test your MWE? It lacks packages to be able to compile.

Comment: re edited and tested...the result is the image attached...may I include  other code lines from *.cls file?

Comment: In order to construct an MWE you could have just used the code from [Martin Scharrer's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57531/106162) and added the lines which break it `\usepackage{float} \floatstyle{boxed} \restylefloat{figure}`, given the issue is not localised to a non-standard class there's no reason to use a non-standard class in your MWE (it just means that others can't compile it straight off) likewise the `\captionsetup` and `\graphicspath` don't seem necessary to break the example so don't include them.