# How to suppress: Rotated caption in the table automatically adjust row height to the length of the text

Tags: tabularx, rotating

I have a image and its caption. I would like to put the caption sideways as it is shown in the question ["how-to-rotate-exclusively-the-caption-of-a-figure"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380314/how-to-rotate-exclusively-the-caption-of-a-figure), but the problem is that I am not able to set row height. I would like to have the caption text to be aligned in a block with its length, determined by the height of the page or the expected height of the image (see figure below).

Is here only way to use `\parbox`?

**MNWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}
    \refstepcounter{figure}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|}
      \hline \\
      \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,
                       height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
          &
      \rotatebox{90}{Obrázek~\thefigure: Long dummy text that can't be wrapped} \\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Putting cell content within a tabular environment will center the content both vertically and horizontally.

The definition of new types of columns (`\newcolumntype` package `array`) allows to control the width of the cells. In the first tabular level, the width of the caption cell, in the second tabular level --because it is rotated--, the height of the caption cell.

Type `W` sets a cell with centered content, type `H` with `raggedright` content.

Using the same length for both the image height and the caption simplifies the setup, as in:

```
\begin{tabular}{c}\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\end{tabular} &
            \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{H{0.2\textheight}} % height of caption<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Using the full height of the text area

[image: a]

Changing alignment,  width and height of the caption.

[image: b]

(The figure counter increments automatically, `\refstepcounter{figure}` is not needed)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{array}%\newcolumntype <<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\newcolumntype{W}[1]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{#1}}% caption row centered
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{ >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} m{#1}} % caption row  raggedright
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1ex}%vertical padding

    \begin{figure*}
%       \refstepcounter{figure}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|W{1cm}|}% width of caption <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            \begin{tabular}{c}\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\end{tabular} &
          \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{W{\textheight}}  % height of caption <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        Obrázek~\thefigure: Long dummy text that can't be wrapped \\        
        \end{tabular}}\\
    \hline      
        \end{tabular}
    \end{figure*}   


\begin{figure*}
    %       \refstepcounter{figure} % not needed <<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{tabular}{|c|W{3cm}|} % width of caption <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \hline
        \begin{tabular}{c}\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\end{tabular} &
        \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{W{4cm}} %height of caption
                Obrázek~\thefigure: Long dummy text that can't be wrapped \\        
        \end{tabular}}\\
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
    
\begin{figure*}
    %       \refstepcounter{figure}% not needed 
    \begin{tabular}{|c|W{2cm}|}% width of caption <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \hline
        \begin{tabular}{c}\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}\end{tabular} &
        \rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{H{4cm}} % height of caption<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                Obrázek~\thefigure: Long dummy text that can't be wrapped \\    
        \end{tabular}}\\
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}   

\end{document}
```